# Rails: validate presence of parent_id in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, models, nested-forms

I have a projects resource that has many tasks. I want to ensure that every task has a `project_id` by adding `validates_presence_of :project_id` to the tasks model.

However, when creating a new project with tasks, the project_id won't be available until the record saves, therefore I can't use `validates_presence_of :project_id`.

So my question is, how do I validate presence of project_id in the task model? I want to ensure every task has a parent.

...

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
```

...

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :project
 validates_presence_of :project_id
```

Comment: This question isn't making much sense to me. You want a task to belong to a project without having a project to begin with... how is it possible to get an id for something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you creating tasks through a nested form when you create the project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your code works:

- If you validates_presence_of :project, then as long as the project is there, it will validate. But if your project is unsaved, you could still save the task.
- If you validates_presence_of :project_id, then the integer must be there, indicating a saved value.

Here's rSpec that proves the point. If you validate :project_id, you can't save a task without saving the Project.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

/specs/model_specs/task_spec.rb

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe Task do

  before(:each) do 
    @project = Project.new
  end

  it "should require a project_id, not just a project object" do
    task = Task.new
    task.project = @project
    Task.instance_eval("validates_presence_of :project_id")
    task.valid?.should == false
  end

  it "should not be valid without a project" do
    task = Task.new
    task.project = @project
    Task.instance_eval("validates_presence_of :project")
    task.valid?.should == false
    task.save.should == false
  end

end
```

Comment: I want to mark your answer as correct but the check mark is gone :/

Answer (score 15):

See [here](http://pivotallabs.com/users/stevend/blog/articles/1259-standup-5-28-2010-rails-new-inverse-of-association-option-automatically-creates-backreferences) for the definitive answer :

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :project
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :project
 validates_presence_of :project
```

Not so elegant if you ask me... It should transparently validate.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I don't understand something, but it looks like you are trying to cheat rails. Why don't you just do like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validate_presence_of :project
end
```

Comment: This is a super old question:  But, the reason you can't do a simple association validation is because the task is in :fields_for...they are nested in the :project form.  On save, the project_id will not be available yet for validation and the validation will fail.  You can test this by simply removing the validation for :project.  The :inverse_of ensures the association is in tact at save.  https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2815-nested-models-build-should-directly-assign-the-parent

One thing I have done in the past is add: `validates_presence_of :parent_id, :on => :update`. Not great but it helps tighten the net a little.

Comment: This completely neglects the create action.  Not good.  Use :inverse_of to ensure your parent object is associated at save in nested fields.  https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having the same issue I dealt with. I have two models, Account and User, and when the account is created the first user is created through a `@account.users.build`. The User model has a `validates_presence_of :account` validation.

To make the first user pass validation, I added the following code to my Account model:

```
  before_validation_on_create :initialize_users

  def initialize_users
    users.each { |u| u.account = self }
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In reality you need both:

```
validates_presence_of project
validates_presence_of project_id
```

That way the task will not be saved in either of the following cases assuming that you have only 2 valid projects in the database, i.e. project id 99 is invalid:

```
task.project_id = 99
task.save

task.project = Project.new
task.save
```

I hope this is of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Project` class must define

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
```

See [Nested Model Form on Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for more details on how to make the form.

---

EDIT:

In your form you should have something like this:

`_form.html.erb`

```
<% form_for @project do |f| %> 
    # project fields...
    <% f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'task_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add task", f, :tasks %></p>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`_task_fields.html.erb`

```
<%= f.label :name, "Task name:" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
# task fields...
<%= link_to_remove_fields "Delete task", f, :tasks %>
```

`link_to_add_fields` and `link_to_remove_fields` are methods defined in application_helper to add/delete fields dynamically.

Comment: hmn - good question. So when they are saved together it doesn't create projects first, then the tasks?

Comment: Well, it first saves the project, then the resulted id goes to the `project_id` of the task