# Testing association through aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm new to TDD and Rails.
I'm trying to test an 'aliased' association (don't know if this is a valid term).

My test:

```rb
it 'an order should always have a customer' do
  o = Order.new
  o.should_not be_valid
end
```

My model:

```rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => Person
  validates_associated :customer
end
```

I don't know if **validates_associated** does what It implies. My test still counts orders with 'custumer_id: nil' as valid.

The Person model:

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :middle_name
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name

  has_many :addresses
  has_many :orders, :as => :customer
end
```

I want to make sure that every Order saved has an associated custumer (a Person object).
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validates_associated` only tells the Model that validations should be run on associated objects as well (have a look at the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)).  You still need to add a validation on `Order`.  Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155396/validates-presence-of-with-belongs-to-associations-the-right-way).  I could be wrong, but I think it will point you in the direction of what you're looking for.

Comment: I added a **validates_presence_of** and it seems to be working. Thanks.