# Redundant validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859384/rails-validate-presence-of-parent-id-in-has-many-association/3017982#3017982), that covers the difference between validating a belongs_to object vs. its id, I have a related question:

I have the following validation

```
validates_presence_of :batch_id
validates_numericality_of :batch_id, :only_integer => true, :greater_than => 0
```

Is the second additional check validates the :batch_id worthwhile, or is it redundant?

In theory, Rails knows the semantic meaning of batch_id and can validate it more thoroughly than it just being present.  I wouldn't, for instance, want a value of -1 for batch_id getting through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
belongs_to :batch
validates_presence_of :batch
```

In this case Rails will check specified batch id for existing in database. If you use `validates_presence_of :batch_id`, Rails will only check presense of batch_id property as integer. If you dont' want to check for existing in database but want it to be positive, you should use `validates_numericality_of`, it's not redundant.